# Selects/dropdowns reflecting current date?

Tags: php, html

I'm building a website for a client (I'm a designer who's trying to learn to code) and have a three selects.

It looks like this:

[image]

Now the client wants the arrival date to reflect the current date in all of the selects. How can I accomplish this with PHP?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
 $date = new DateTime();
 $day = $date->format('d');
 $month = $date->format('m');
 $year = $date->format('Y');
```

Then when you generate your select

```
<select name="day">
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
{
  printf('<option value="%d" %s>%d</option>', $i, $i == $day ? 'selected="selected"' : '', $i);
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$months = array(1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb', 3 => 'Mar', 4 => 'Apr', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'Jun', 7 => 'Jul', 8 => 'Aug', 9 => 'Sep', 10 => 'Oct', 11 => 'Nov', 12 => 'Dec');
?>

<select name="month">
    <?php foreach($months as $key => $month) { ?>
        <?php $default_month = ($key == $date->format('m'))?'selected':''; ?>
        <option <?php echo $default_month; ?> value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <?php echo $month; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>


<select name="day">
    <?php for($day = 1; $day <= 31; $day++) { ?>
        <?php $default_day = ($day == $date->format('d'))?'selected':''; ?>
        <option <?php echo $default_day; ?> value="<?php echo $day; ?>">
            <?php echo $day; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>


<select name="year">
    <?php for($year = $date->format('Y'); $year <= 2020; $year++) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $year; ?>">
            <?php echo $year; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```